# WPF Command can execute not responding

Tags: c#, wpf, command, selection

I have a WPF command on a button for an option to apply on a ListView item, and the can execute action is related to the listview selection, if the selected items count is superior to zero.

```
private void DeleteItemCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = SomeListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
    }
```

Problem is, even when I select one or more items, the command can never execute. I know I can refresh all the commands with `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` but I don't know if it will work, and how to do it here ? Every 1 sec ?

Comment: Can you check if method is being called at all?

Comment: Problem might be that the command's CanExecute is never run when the selectedItems are changed ( NotifyPropertyChanged)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this.

**First way:** Create a new class for every single command.

```
public class PlusCommand : ICommand
{
    private YourViewModelClass viewModel;
    public PlusCommand(YourViewModelClass vm)
    {
        viewModel = vm;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //Your code to run here. Access viewmodel by viewModel variable.
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

**Second way:** Create a RelayCommand class and use RelayCommand class for every command in the future.

Step 1: Create the RelayCommand class.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand    
{    
    private Action<object> execute;    
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged    
    {    
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }    
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }    
    }    

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)    
    {    
        this.execute = execute;    
        this.canExecute = canExecute;    
    }    

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)    
    {    
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);    
    }    

    public void Execute(object parameter)    
    {    
        this.execute(parameter);    
    }    
}
```

Step 2: Declare a new command by RelayCommand

```
RelayCommand PlusCommand= new RelayCommand(o => DoSomething(), o => true);
```

You can [read more here.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` or raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event for the command whenever `SomeListView.SelectedItems.Count` changes. You could detect when this happens by handling the `SelectionChanged` event for the `ListView`:

```
private void SomeListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Comment: @betsou: Then you need to post the implementation of your command and everything else that is relevant if you want any further help.